# What color filter does Night Shift apply?

Tags: iphone, ios

On iOS 15 what color filter does Night Shift apply?

I would like to be able to edit a normal photo on my MacBook and make it look like it would if it were displayed on an iPhone that has night shift turned on. How can I perfectly apply the same color filter that this setting does?

Comment: according to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207570) the colors of the display are shifted to warmer colors. Depending on the software you use to process or edit your pictures you can change “warmth”

Comment: For example, the Snapseed app has a Warmth option within the Tune Image tool, and the native Photos app has a Cast slider within the Color editing option.

Comment: You can [do this directly in Apple Photos](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/photos/pht9b1d4a744/mac) on your Mac.

Comment: @slartibartfast that doesn't look the same

Comment: Night Shift certainly moves the color spectrum from cooler (blue) towards warmer (yellow). Maybe you refer to True Tone?

Comment: Night shift alone does blue light reduction - color temperature ranges from about 5000K during the day to going down to 1900K during the night.